# Split the list by consecutive common element

Tags: python

I have the following list that contain only two characters 'N' and 'C'

```
ls = ['N', 'N', 'N', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'N', 'C', 'C']
```

What I want to do is to extract the consecutive "C"s and return the index in the list.

Yielding something like

```
  chunk1 = [('C', 'C', 'C', 'C'), [3,4,5,6]]
  chunk2 = [('C', 'C'), [8,9]]

  # and when there's no C it returns empty list.
```

How can I achieve that in Python?

I tried this but didn't do as I hoped:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
tmp = (list(g) for k, g in groupby(enumerate(ls), itemgetter(1)) if k == 'C')
zip(*tmp)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the `zip(*...)` inside the list comprehension:

```
import itertools as IT
import operator

ls = ['N', 'N', 'N', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'N', 'C', 'C']

[list(zip(*g))[::-1] 
 for k, g in IT.groupby(enumerate(ls), operator.itemgetter(1)) 
 if k == 'C']
```

yields

```
[[('C', 'C', 'C', 'C'), (3, 4, 5, 6)], [('C', 'C'), (8, 9)]]
```

---

In Python2, `list(zip(...))` can be replaced by `zip(...)`, but since in Python3 `zip` returns an iterator, there we would need `list(zip(...))`. To make the solution compatible with both Python2 and Python3, use `list(zip(...))` here.

Answer (score 2):

Use generator function. all you need to do is to reverse the `group` when unzipping the group.
so use  `yield zip(*group)[::-1]`

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
def solve(ls):
    for key, group in groupby(enumerate(ls), itemgetter(1)):
        if key =='C':
            yield zip(*group)[::-1]

ls =  ['N', 'N', 'N', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'N', 'C', 'C']
print list(solve(ls))


[[('C', 'C', 'C', 'C'), (3, 4, 5, 6)], [('C', 'C'), (8, 9)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls = ['N', 'N', 'N', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'N', 'C', 'C']

def whereMyCharsAt(haystack, needle):
    start = None
    for ii, char in enumerate(haystack):
        if char == needle:
            if start is None:
                start = ii
        else:
            if start is not None:
                yield [needle] * (ii - start), range(start, ii)
                start = None

    if start is not None:
        yield [needle] * (len(haystack) - start), range(start, len(haystack))

for indexes in whereMyCharsAt(ls, 'C'):
    print indexes
```

This prints:

```
(['C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], [3, 4, 5, 6])
(['C', 'C'], [8, 9])
```